# Multithreading in JFreeChart with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jfreechart

I'm developing a monitoring program that connects to remote servers and gets i/o rates. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickUnitType;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimePeriod;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeTableXYDataset;


public class IOStat extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    FileRW FRW;
    Sessionn SES;
    String SONUC;
    String SUTUN;
    String[] st;
    int SECIM; 
    int NODE; 
    private static final int COUNT = 650;
    String deger;
     String[] degerler;

    Timer timer;
    String TITLE;
    private static String Y_EKSEN;
    private static String X_EKSEN;
    String SUTUNLAR = null;
    int i;
    int sayac;
    Thread t;
    TimeTableXYDataset dataset;

    public IOStat(String title, String yEksen, String xEksen, Sessionn obj, int node, String[] label) {
        SES = new Sessionn();
        SES.girisYap(obj.USERNAME, obj.PASSWORD, obj.HOSTNAME);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        t = new Thread(this, title);
        i = 0;
        sayac = label.length;
        NODE = node;
        SES = obj;
        Y_EKSEN = yEksen;
        X_EKSEN = xEksen;
        TITLE = title;
        st = label;
        dataset = new TimeTableXYDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = createAreaChart(dataset);
        this.add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        t.start();
    }

    private JFreeChart createAreaChart(TimeTableXYDataset dataset) {
       JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedXYAreaChart(
                TITLE, X_EKSEN, Y_EKSEN, dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
        DateAxis domainAxis = new DateAxis();
        domainAxis.setAutoRange(true);
        domainAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new ThreadSafeSimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"));
        domainAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.MINUTE, 5));
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setAutoRange(true);
        axis.setFixedAutoRange(3600000.0); //1 saat
        rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new DecimalFormat("#,###.########"));
        rangeAxis.setAutoRange(true);
        return chart;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                  TimePeriod  period = new Second();
              deger = SES.sorguCalistir("ssh " + TITLE + " iostat -k -x 1 2 | perl -e 'local $/=\"\"; @p=<STDIN>; print @p[4];' | awk '{ print $6 \" \" $7}' | grep -v rsec |awk '{ SUM += $1; SUM2 += $2} END { print SUM \" \" SUM2 }'");
               degerler=null;
              degerler = deger.split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

                    dataset.add(period, Double.parseDouble(degerler[j]), st[j]);
                    if (dataset.getItemCount() > COUNT) {
                        TimePeriod firstItemTime = dataset.getTimePeriod(0);
                        dataset.remove(firstItemTime, st[j]);
                    }
                }

                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(IOStat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

When i run this code, it works well in the beginning but after two seconds, there is going some kind of data corruption in dataset values. My  string array `degerler` is randomly getting different values that it shouldn't. Also i heard that SimpleDateFormat is not-ThreadSafe. But in order to solve this, my `period` is created as local variable in `run()` function, as you can see on my codes.

The exception is like below:

```
Exception in thread "alzproddbadm02" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0
0"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at OsWatch.IOStat.run(IOStat.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Exception in thread "alzproddbadm01" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0
0"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at OsWatch.IOStat.run(IOStat.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Mar 03, 2014 4:53:27 PM OsWatch.IOStat run
SEVERE: null
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at OsWatch.IOStat.run(IOStat.java:114)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

When i put the `deger` value to the console and trace it, here is the output:

```
run:
deger=
deger=
Exception in thread "alzproddbadm02" Exception in thread "alzproddbadm01" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1011)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at OsWatch.IOStat.run(IOStat.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1011)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at OsWatch.IOStat.run(IOStat.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
deger=0 0

deger=0 0

deger=0 468

deger=0 468
0 1764

Exception in thread "alzproddbadm04" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "468
0"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at OsWatch.IOStat.run(IOStat.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
deger=0 0

deger=0 1104

deger=0 0

deger=0 0

deger=0 696

deger=0 0

deger=0 0

deger=0 0

deger=0 0

deger=0 12

deger=0 0

deger=0 0

BUILD STOPPED (total time: 44 seconds)
```

Comment: Have you put a system.out.println("deger=" + deger) for the data being split to help determine where the problem is occurring?

Comment: I put and edited my question. As you can see, sometimes there is more than 2 values. That's a problem, because of my split function has to get only two values, not four.

Comment: Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @D-Klotz, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: most probably the problem is that you modify the dataSet off the EDT

Comment: Do you own this class and method? SES.sorguCalistir    If you are seeing more data than you expect and it is a direct result of this method call, (as in, you put your system#out right after this call) then you have to suspect something going wrong within that call. Or, is it possible you have more threads active than what you are showing?  EDT == basically means the event dispatch thread. If you have no idea what that means you need to do some reading. It is the only thread where you can do updates to Swing components.

Comment: The other thing I would do is write my own bash shell script that invokes the long shell command you have there over and over and see if the output is always what you expect. Maybe your problem has nothing to do with java.

Comment: No, i found my problem. It's about session numbers. When i try to ssh 4 connections with only 1 session, it causes errors. I should open 1 connection for every remote server.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that i have to remove this line

```
  SES = obj;
```

Because it overrides my `SES` object and causes data confusion, also session locks.

Comment: good you found it - but it's not the only problem with your code: you **must** access all swing properties (data inclusive) on the EDT.

Comment: Why must i access all swing properties?

Comment: don't understand the question - you are changing the dataset in your thread, don't you? Or are the remove/add methods documented to be allow usage by any thread? (they _might_ take over the switching to the EDT internally, don't know ;)

Comment: In JFreeChart, chart is updated automatically when dataset values changed. So, this solution works for now. But i have to study about EDT either.

Comment: yeah, I know they are updated - the question is who is responsible for guaranteeing the update on the EDT. My bet would be on client code (same as in all core swing data/models) - it's a guess, though. You better check soon, as EDT violations will sooner or later lead to nasty errors which are hard to trace/debug. Good luck!